# Swift Cocoa, obtain Resources path

Tags: swift, cocoa, path, bundle

I would like to know how to obtain in Swift, the path of the Contents/Resources folder in the "Show Package Contents" of the application I am developing. 
Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [resourcePath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1417723-resourcepath) function:

```
var path = Bundle.main.resourcePath;
```

Comment: glad to be useful. you can accept my answer if it worked for you.